# Identify an Online Puzzle: Website Based Puzzle

Tags: puzzle-identification

Around 2007-2009, I was introduced to a website which hid puzzle clues in website data such as picture code as well as normal puzzles using various different types of code breaking and cyphers.  The goal was to find the next url to progress with the puzzle.  The puzzle eventually ended as the site was not being updated and it even had a forum for help along the way.  Any ideas on what the site was and if it still exists?

Comment: Do you remember anything else about the puzzle site? What it looked like, what the challenges were about...? (I ask, because there are several possibilities in my mind, and additional details help.)

Comment: It was primarily images with puzzles either in the image itself or hidden in the code of the page or the image code.  The main .com url was always consistent but the page name after the slash was determined by the puzzle answer for each step.

Comment: [The Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/about.php) is a fairly early example of this sort of site (the domain was registered in 2005 according to WHOIS). Although it doesn't sound exactly like what you're describing...

Comment: There are too many websites of that variety to name. Notpron, Tricky's Riddles, and ze?t are three that I've personally played.

Comment: @JoeZ. I think it's too broad.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The riddle series you were looking for was [Tricky's Riddles](http://www.totallytricky.co.uk/riddle/ame.php). It's an old puzzler that I myself came across in 2006 back when a bunch of my middle-school friends introduced me to it, and back when it didn't have a domain and was still being hosted in a University of Exeter home directory. Looking back at it, the riddles were really shoddy and much too "random", but back then it was the ultimate challenge for us.

However, there are quite a few more riddle pages that fit that description, including [Notpron](http://deathball.net/notpron) and [ze?t](http://zestriddle.ovh.org/hints.htm), out of the ones I've personally played and failed at (ze?t appears to be down at the moment).

Comment: Menawhile, if you like website-based puzzles, I'll plug mine: [The Temple of Quetzalcoatl](http://joezeng.com/quetzalcoatl/). So far it has 19 levels, but nobody who's tried it has gotten past level 17 yet.

Comment: Can we take this conversation to chat?

Comment: Although it seems that could be the right site, Dracula's Riddle is another one that was very well-known in terms play length with an appropriate learning curve.

Comment: @Chrismas007 We can take it to an IRC chatroom, but I don't like talking about ToQ in Stack Exchange chat rooms because those are publicly logged.

Comment: @JoeZ. Sounds good let me know.

Comment: Notpron was the one I played back in the day.